# Animation for CAShapeLayer: Why would -insertSublayer:atIndex: botch animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I have a number of CAShapeLayers that are already sublayers to the layer of a view (UIView). I'm able to animate their paths without any trouble. However, I need to add some additional shape layers later on and then animate all of the paths for all of the shape layers. When I attempt to insert new sublayers, the animation no longer occurs. The view gets rendered with all the shape layers in their final states.

Here is the block of code that I'm dealing with. When I comment it out, the paths for the existing layers animate just fine. Can someone tell me what's going on?

```
for (int i = oldPoints.count; i < newPoints.count; i++)
    [self.layer insertSublayer: [CAShapeLayer layer] atIndex: ++layerIndex];
```

Also, I've tried calling -addSublayer: and I get the same results.

My animation code in my superview looks like this:

```
[UIView animationWithDuration: 0.2
                   animations: ^{

                       for (ComponentView *view in _componentViews)
                           [view reloadDataWithAnimation: YES];

                       [self layoutComponentViews];
                   }
                   completion: ^(BOOL finished) {

                   }];
```

Within -reloadDataWithAnimation: in my ComponentView, I have the following code:

```
- (void) reloadDataWithAnimation: (BOOL) animate {

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < oldData.count; rowIndex++) {

        NSArray     *oldPoints  = [oldData objectAtIndex: rowIndex];
        NSArray     *newPoints  = nil;

        if (rowIndex < newData.count)
            newPoints = [newData objectAtIndex: rowIndex];


        if (newPoints.count > oldPoints.count) {

            layerIndex += oldPoints.count;

            for (int i = oldPoints.count; i < newPoints.count; i++)
                [self.layer insertSublayer: [CAShapeLayer layer] atIndex: ++layerIndex];

        }
        else if (newPoints.count < oldPoints.count) {

            layerIndex += newPoints.count;

            for (int i = newPoints.count; i < oldPoints.count; i++)
                [disposableLayers addObject: [self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex: ++layerIndex]];

        }
        else {

            if (newPoints.count > 0)
                layerIndex += newPoints.count;

        }
    }

    if (newData.count > oldData.count) {

        for (int rowIndex = oldData.count; rowIndex < newData.count; rowIndex++) {

            NSArray *newPoints = [newData objectAtIndex: rowIndex];

            for (int i = 1; i < newPoints.count; i++)
                [self.layer insertSublayer: [CAShapeLayer layer] atIndex: ++layerIndex];

        }
    }

    /*  code that iterates through old and new data structures  */

        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
        [animation setFromValue: (__bridge id) oldPath];
        [animation setToValue: (__bridge id) newPath];
        [animation setFillMode: kCAFillModeForwards];
        [animation setDuration: _defaultAnimationDuration];

        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer *) [self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex: layerIndex];
        [shapeLayer setPath: newPath];
        [shapeLayer setStrokeColor: [self strokeColorForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath].CGColor];
        [shapeLayer setLineWidth: self.lineWidth];
        [shapeLayer addAnimation: animation forKey: @"path"];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have a good guess as to what the reason is, but it would be helpful if you'd show your animation code.

Comment: Also please say where you are making the `insertSublayer` call. Is it at the same time as the animation?

Comment: matt, I edited my question above to include the additional content you requested.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the `UIView animationWithDuration:` call supposed to do? The `animations:` block should contain code that sets some animatable view properties, but I don't see that happening.

Comment: Also, is some code omitted? I only see you animating one shape layer. Forgive me if I'm being dense.

Comment: -reloadDataWithAnimation: is called from within the animation block. The subsequent block of code that creates the additional shape layers resides in the implementation of -reloadDataWithAnimation:. Sorry that wasn't clear. I've added that to the question above.

Comment: Yes, but you're not quite answering my first question. Wouldn't this code work just as well if there were *no* `UIView animationWithDuration:` call? You say it but I don't see you doing any view animation, so why not just drop it? The shape layer animation will still work just as well without it.

Comment: Also you're saying `shapeLayer addAnimation: animation forKey: @"path"`, but what *is* `animation`? I don't see it defined. Surely this is the whole point - the animation that is or isn't happening? That is what I would need to see, is it not?

Comment: @matt There's a call to `[self layoutComponentViews]` which will set the frames of the component subviews and those changes need to be animated. Also, some subclasses of this ComponentView class can change their view properties in their own implementations of `-reloadDataWithAnimation:`.

Comment: I've added the code that creates the animation.

Comment: Well, I didn't find the exact problem, sorry: too complex for me to take in. But the usual reason why a layer animation gets cancelled is that something else sets the same property directly. I wonder if it would help to use delayed performance? Step out of the current runloop and wait for the next one, giving the new interface with the new sublayers a chance to "settle down", before starting your CABasicAnimation on the shape layer. Not much help but it's something to try...